# can we setup a sync of databases between on-premises MySQL server to Azure Database for MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, azure-mysql-database

by using mysqldump I am able to migrate data from on-premises to Azure Database for MySQL. but now after dump and restore i want to create a continuous sync between them. how's it possible?
I have followed below link but havn't achieved it. Is it possible or not?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-data-in-replication#other-useful-stored-procedures-for-data-in-replication-operations

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no prebuilt service available in azure.

You can find more information on this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-data-sql-server-sql-database)

[image]